# How do I copy a local file to a pod's container in my minikube cluster using the Go client?

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubectl

My query is pretty much what the title says, I have a local file say `file.txt` and I want to copy it into `pod1`'s container `container1`.

If I was to do it using kubectl, the appropriate command would be :

`kubectl cp file.txt pod1:file.txt -c container1`

However, how do I do it using the Go client of kubectl?

I tried 2 ways but none of them worked :

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "context"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"

    g "github.com/sdslabs/katana/configs"
    v1 "k8s.io/api/core/v1"
    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/labels"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/client-go/rest"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
    //"k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/exec"
)

func CopyIntoPod(namespace string, podName string, containerName string, srcPath string, dstPath string) {
    // Create a Kubernetes client
    config, err := GetKubeConfig()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    client, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Build the command to execute
    cmd := []string{"cp", srcPath, dstPath}

    // Use the PodExecOptions struct to specify the options for the exec request
    options := v1.PodExecOptions{
        Container: containerName,
        Command:   cmd,
        Stdin:     false,
        Stdout:    true,
        Stderr:    true,
        TTY:       false,
    }
    log.Println("Options set!")

    // Use the CoreV1Api.Exec method to execute the command inside the container
    req := client.CoreV1().RESTClient().Post().
        Namespace(namespace).
        Name(podName).
        Resource("pods").
        SubResource("exec").
        VersionedParams(&options, metav1.ParameterCodec)
    log.Println("Request generated")
    
    exec, err := req.Stream(context.TODO())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer exec.Close()

    // Read the response from the exec command
    var result []byte
    if _, err := exec.Read(result); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("File copied successfully!")
}
```

This gave me the error message :

`no kind is registered for the type v1.PodExecOptions in scheme "pkg/runtime/scheme.go:100"`

I couldn't figure it out, so I tried another way :

```
type PodExec struct {
    RestConfig *rest.Config
    *kubernetes.Clientset
}

func NewPodExec(config *rest.Config, clientset *kubernetes.Clientset) *PodExec {
    config.APIPath = "/api" // Make sure we target /api and not just /
    config.GroupVersion = &schema.GroupVersion{Version: "v1"} // this targets the core api groups so the url path will be /api/v1
    config.NegotiatedSerializer = serializer.WithoutConversionCodecFactory{CodecFactory: scheme.Codecs}
    return &PodExec{
      RestConfig: config,
      Clientset:  clientset,
    }  
}

func (p *PodExec) PodCopyFile(src string, dst string, containername string, podNamespace string) (*bytes.Buffer, *bytes.Buffer, *bytes.Buffer, error) {
    ioStreams, in, out, errOut := genericclioptions.NewTestIOStreams()
    copyOptions := cp.NewCopyOptions(ioStreams)
    copyOptions.Clientset = p.Clientset
    copyOptions.ClientConfig = p.RestConfig
    copyOptions.Container = containername
    copyOptions.Namespace = podNamespace
    err := copyOptions.Run()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, nil, fmt.Errorf("could not run copy operation: %v", err)
    }
    return in, out, errOut, nil
}
```

However, there were some issues with the `copyOptions.Run()` command, it tried to look for `o.args[0] and o.args[0]` inside copyOptions but `o` is not imported so it couldn't be modified.

Context : https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/cp#CopyOptions.Run

So, now I'm really lost and confused. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit : I did think of a viable method where we can just call `cmd.exec()` and run the `kubectl cp` command directly but it seems kinda hacky and I'm not sure whether it would work, any thoughts?

Comment: I might avoid this workflow – are you planning to copy the same file into all 5 replicas of your deployment, plus the ones a HorizontalPodAutoscaler dynamically creates, and also repopulate the file when a node goes down and a pod is recreated on a different node?  Can you do whatever setup is required here inside the container itself, either in a startup script of some sort or in response to a network request?

Comment: A more k8s-way of giving the file to the pods would be use the k8s api or kubectl or go api to put the data in a configmap entry.  This entry could be exposed to the pod via ENV VAR or via volume mount.  This would ensure when k8s restarts the pod the data survives - see comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I finally managed to do it :

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"

    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes/scheme"
    corev1 "k8s.io/api/core/v1"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
    "k8s.io/client-go/util/homedir"
    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/remotecommand"
)

func CopyIntoPod(podName string, namespace string, containerName string, srcPath string, dstPath string) {
    // Get the default kubeconfig file
    kubeConfig := filepath.Join(homedir.HomeDir(), ".kube", "config")

    // Create a config object using the kubeconfig file
    config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", kubeConfig)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error creating config: %s\n", err)
        return
    }

    // Create a Kubernetes client
    client, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error creating client: %s\n", err)
        return
    }

    // Open the file to copy
    localFile, err := os.Open(srcPath)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error opening local file: %s\n", err)
        return
    }
    defer localFile.Close()

    pod, err := client.CoreV1().Pods(namespace).Get(context.TODO(), podName, metav1.GetOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error getting pod: %s\n", err)
        return
    }

    // Find the container in the pod
    var container *corev1.Container
    for _, c := range pod.Spec.Containers {
        if c.Name == containerName {
            container = &c
            break
        }
    }

    if container == nil {
        fmt.Printf("Container not found in pod\n")
        return
    }

    // Create a stream to the container
    req := client.CoreV1().RESTClient().Post().
        Resource("pods").
        Name(podName).
        Namespace(namespace).
        SubResource("exec").
        Param("container", containerName)   

    req.VersionedParams(&corev1.PodExecOptions{
        Container: containerName,
        Command:   []string{"bash", "-c", "cat > " + dstPath},
        Stdin:     true,
        Stdout:    true,
        Stderr:    true,
    }, scheme.ParameterCodec)

    exec, err := remotecommand.NewSPDYExecutor(config, "POST", req.URL())
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error creating executor: %s\n", err)
        return
    }

    // Create a stream to the container
    err = exec.StreamWithContext(context.TODO(), remotecommand.StreamOptions{
        Stdin:  localFile,
        Stdout: os.Stdout,
        Stderr: os.Stderr,
        Tty:    false,
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error streaming: %s\n", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("File copied successfully")
}
```